# Conjugation as a group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Disclaimer: my question is different from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970623/showing-that-conjugation-is-a-group-action) question.

I am following [these math notes](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eapaulin/AbstractAlgebra.pdf) on abstract algebra that I found online to teach myself. On page 21 the group action of conjugation is defined as: $$\mu:(x,y)\mapsto x^{-1}*y*x$$
In the [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970623/showing-that-conjugation-is-a-group-action) it is defined as: $$\mu_\text{(other question)}:(x,y)\mapsto x*y*x^{-1}$$
Which works out.

Since we require: $$\mu(x*y,z)=\mu(x,\mu(y,z))$$
I find that the LHS is: $$\mu(x*y,z)=(x*y)^{-1}*z*(x*y)=y^{-1}*x^{-1}*z*x*y$$
Whereas the RHS is: $$\mu(x,\mu(y,z))=\mu(x,y^{-1}*z*y)=x^{-1}*y^{-1}*z*y*x$$
So clearly $$\mu(x*y,z)\neq\mu(x,\mu(y,z))$$

Is there a mistake on my end or did the author mean to define it as: $\mu:(x,y)\mapsto x*y*x^{-1}$?

Comment: A good mental model for conjugation is changing coordinates (this can be made precise). Your question comes down to this: should we think of a rotation as spinning the paper or moving the points? You'll sometimes hear these talked about as passive vs. active transformations. Can you work out which is which in this case?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins In terms of transforms, I think of the inverse occurring on the right. Because our new coordinate needs to be brought back to the original frame, acted on, and then transformed into the new frame. This seems to suggest there is a typo and it should be $\mu:(x,y)\mapsto x*y*x^{-1}$. Unless the typo is in the condition $\mu(x*y,z)=\mu(x,\mu(y,z))$ which needs to be changed?

Comment: It depends on whether you mean a left group action or a right group action, I think. Does the question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261660/is-there-a-standard-notation-for-conjugation help?

Comment: @QPhysl I realize I misread your question. I thought you were wondering about the distinction between $xyx^{-1}$ and $x^{-1}yx$. Yes, Steve Kass is right. The difference in definition comes down to left vs. right group actions.

Comment: You defined $\mu(x,y)$ to have the inverse on the right, but then when you evaluate $\mu(x*y,z)$ you put the inverse on the left...

Comment: @coiso, No I specifically define it on the left and continue this every time except when I show $\mu_\text{(other question)}$. It seems most people put it on the right which is why I brought that point up

Comment: @CharlesHudgins, sorry I don't exactly follow the difference. The resource I'm using defines the group action as satisfying two axioms, the first is: $\forall x,y\in G, s\in S,\mu(x*y,s)=\mu(x,\mu(y,s))$ for $\mu:G\times S\rightarrow S$. In our case $S=G$ and I'm looking at a group action defined as the "conjugation". If it depends on the right/left group action isn't this saying a different group action (conjugation) depends on the definition of another group action (the left vs right group action)?

Comment: The axiom μ(x∗y,s)=μ(x,μ(y,s)) is for a left group action. The difference in the two definitions of conjugation is that one is a left action and the other is a right action.

Comment: For a right action the axiom would be μ(x∗y,s)=μ(y, μ(x, s)).

Comment: The simplest explanation may be that your source has an inconsistency where they defined a group action as a left action but when they defined conjugation, they defined it as a right action.

Comment: I agree with Steve Kass, scleaver and Ted who know this at least as well as I do. This is the difference between a *left action* vs. a *right action*. About conjugation in particular, many authors use right action simply because they write $x^g$ for the conjugate. With the acting element $g$ *on the right*, we want the rule to be $(x^g)^h=x^{gh}$, and this, in turn, forces us to define $x^g=g^{-1}xg$ as opposed to $x^g=gxg^{-1}$. FWIW in my lecture notes I do define conjugation as $gxg^{-1}$ because I default to left actions (I'm not a group theorist). Then I cannot use exponential notation.

Comment: (cont'd) And students still need to learn about both left/right actions. If a group $G$ acts on a set $X$ from the left, and $A$ is any set, then $G$ naturally acts on the set of functions $f:A\to X$ from the left, but the natural action on the set of functions $f:X\to A$ is from the right. Alternatively you can define right action by $g$ to mean the same thing as left action by $g^{-1}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why not use the notation $^gx$ for $gxg^{-1}$? I usually prefer right actions (mainly because in English and European languages we read from left to right), but when obliged to use left actions I write $^gx$ for conjugation.